# Spring Cloud Function JSON payload

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-cloud-function

I'm developing a function to be deployed as AWS Lambda, in the meantime I'd like to test it locally.
I don't know why, the payload got in the function is a string and not the expected object, this is the code:

```
@Component
public class New implements Function<Message<ApiRequestDTO>,Message<ApiResponseDTO>> {

...

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Message<ApiResponseDTO> apply(Message<ApiRequestDTO> request) {
            // 1. validate request
            validatorService.validate(request.getPayload().getDocument());
```

The **getDocument()** method throws the exception because getPayload() returns a string instead of the object.

This is the request

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/new' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "document": {
    "name": "document_name"
  }
}'
```

Do you know why is it happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I see,
it is related to the JSON parser, basically the document_name is defined as an enum, and if the value is different from expected instead of failing it pass the input as string.

Comment: So do you believe this is an issue on our end or your? Can you also paste your `ApiResponseDTO`. Additionally you don't need use HTTP to test the function. You can get it form catalog and test directly. If you want to test it as close as possible the way it looks in AWS you may want to look at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/main/spring-cloud-function-adapters/spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/adapter/aws/FunctionInvokerTests.java where you can construct the  full json representing Api gateway or any other AWS event

Comment: I solved it myself, but the point is, why SC passes the payload as string instead of trigger an exception due to a malformed request? thank you